# Not able to access a container created by Jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am currently trying a simple scripted pipeline in Jenkins. My project has some tests that need a running S3 server. That is why, I am using Minio.

Here is the `Jenkinsfile` I made:

```groovy
node {
    docker.image('minio/minio').withRun('-p 9000:9000 -e "MINIO_ACCESS_KEY=mykey" -e "MINIO_SECRET_KEY=mysecret"', 'server /data') { c ->
        docker.image('maven:3.5.2-jdk-8-alpine').inside() {
            sh 'mvn clean package'
        }
    }
}
```

The Minio server seems to be started but in the tests, I am trying to access localhost:9000, and I get the following exception :

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to localhost:9000 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

When launching Minio locally with Docker and running my local Maven, I do not have any issue.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `minio/minio` container has its container port 9000 mapped to host port 9000. Your `maven:3.5.2-jdk-8-alpine` container is also started, but it does not have any network access to the `minio` container itself, or to your host. So, running something like `curl localhost:9000` inside of the `maven:3.5.2-jdk-8-alpine` will not get a response.

When you run on your laptop, I am guessing you are running the `minio` container with the `-p 9000:9000` option but *you are running `mvn clean package` from your laptop*. The port is mapped to your laptop's `9000`, and running something like `curl localhost:9000` from your laptop will get a response.

What you need to do, is to make the `minio/minio` container accessible to the `maven:3.5.2-jdk-8-alpine` container. There are a few different ways to do this with [container networking](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/). One way would be to use [a user defined bridge network](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/#use-user-defined-bridge-networks):

```groovy
node {
  sh 'docker network create --driver bridge minio-net'
  docker.image('minio/minio').withRun('--network-alias minio --net minio-net -e "MINIO_ACCESS_KEY=mykey" -e "MINIO_SECRET_KEY=mysecret"', 'server /data') { c ->
    docker.image('maven:3.5.2-jdk-8-alpine').inside('--net minio-net') {
      sh 'nc -zv minio 9000'
      sh 'mvn clean package'
    }
  }
  sh 'docker network rm minio-net'
}
```

In this example:

- a local bridge network is created with name `minio-net`
- the `minio/minio` container is connected to the `minio-net` container with a network-scoped alias of `minio`
- [`nc`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nc) is used to check for connection to `minio:9000` before your build step

You may want to inject an environment variable or something to reference the location of the minio service, which might be `localhost` on your laptop but somewhere else depending on how it is executed.

**NOTE:** I hardcoded the network name for brevity and assumed no failures